# Get the Email ID of user from Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Get the Email ID of user from Facebook PHP SDK

I tried with below codes

First

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');  // or $facebook->api('/me?fields=email')
print_r($user_profile);
```

Second

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query";
    $url .= "?access_token=" . $access_token;
    $url .= "&query=SELECT email FROM user WHERE uid={$user}";
    $userData = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $userEmail = $userData->user->email;
    print_r($userEmail);
```

Third

```
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
$fql    =   "select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square, email from user where uid='$user'";
        $param  =   array(
           'method'     => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'access_token' =>$access_token ,
          'callback'    => ''
        );

        $fqlResult2   =   $facebook->api($param);

    print_r($fqlResult2);
```

None of these will get the email id of login user . How to retrieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FBML** (This will become [history](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml) soon)

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email"></fb:login-button>
```

**PHP**

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
  array(
    'scope' => 'email'
  )
);
```

**JS**

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
       // conosle.log('User logged in');
    } else {
       // console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, {
    scope: 'email'
});​
```

Getting `email` using graph api

```
FB.api('/me', function(user) {
    if (user) {
        User.email = user.email;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Afaik, req_perms is now called "scope". Or am I mixing something up here.

Comment: as far as i remember, it is req_perms in php and scope in js, please correct me if im wrong

Comment: It definitely is "scope" in PHP. We're using that currently, and it works, so ;)

Comment: `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { window.location.reload(); }, {scope:'email'} );` don't works...  But `<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" scope="email"></fb:login-button> ` works fine. Thanks ...

Comment: DO NOT USE FBML! It is deprecated and will be removed from FB in June. See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to the email address of a user. So your application has to ask for the **"email"** [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

[This site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) has some guides how to get those permissions from a user (or rather ask for them).

According to the [JS SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/), you need to do the following:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes,...'});
```

Comment: Yes, How will i give the permission here ?

Comment: I added Javascript SDK and PHP SDK parallelly. So in my code `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        }, {scope:'email'} );` doesn't works...

Comment: `<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" scope="email"></fb:login-button>` works perfectly, but `FB.login` didn't works as it was expected..  Thanks you..

Comment: DO NOT USE FBML! It is deprecated and will be removed from FB in June. See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like the following:

```
$facebook->api('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email' );

getLoginUrl( array(
    'scope' => 'email'
));
```